# How to stream the website data using flume

Tags: api, hadoop, flume

Up to now i have gone through the retrieving tweets using flume.Is there any chance to retrieve a website(eg: airlines related) data using flume with their respective api keys ??.

Answer (score 1):

[NIFI](https://nifi.apache.org/)

This is Apache DataFlow tool it might suits your requirement. It includes Flume and other data source also.